# How to adjust collision margins for objects encapsulated in one another?

Tags: modifiers

I have used the boolean tool to place a cone inside a cube (the cube has the cone shape cut out from it inside). I would like to make them both active objects and have them sit still until something hits it but they immediately try and separate. I have tried changing the collision margins but can't seem to get it so they don't move.

Any ideas? Thanks

[Here is a project to explain](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9g32g3c9KXgQTc4YkF1cnRkZ00/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Best idea is to make the cone slightly smaller. And don't forget to turn Shape from Convex Hull to Mesh for both of them.